# Adding PHP Variable to the end of link -Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, foreach

I am trying to add a variable to the end of an link `<a href="foo.com/$ID">LINK</a>` I am using Laravel and am passing an array of data to the view were its looped through and then displayed.

**View**

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('Search')}}" method="get">
Search<input type="text" name="query" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
  {{Form::token()}}
  </form>
  <br>

<?php if (count($Results) > 0): ?>
<table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 25px 5px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <p></p><th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($Results))); ?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($Results as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row); ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  <tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

this displays.

```
title               place_film_country  wab_id
4th of February     Sri Lanka           266
```

So I am trying to turn the wab_id and pass it into a variable and stick it on the end of the link.

**Controller**

```
public function Search(){
        $query = Input::get('query'); 
            $raw_results =  DB::Table('films')->select('title', 'place_film_country', 'wab_id')
                              ->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                              ->orwhere('place_film_country', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                              ->orwhere('genre', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                              ->orwhere('wab_id', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                              ->get();
             $array = json_decode(json_encode($raw_results), true);

            return View::make('Index')->with('Results', $array);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
```

With something like this:

```
<td><?= $row['title'] ?></td>
<td><?= $row['place_film_country'] ?></td>
<td><a href="http://foo.com/<?= $row['wab_id'] ?>"><?= $row['wab_id'] ?></a></td>
```

Comment: Thank you but if you don't mind me asking why was `<?= $row['wab_id'] ?>` added a second time to the end i removed it and got the same results, just wondering if it was meant to display the id along with "Link".

Comment: 'just wondering if it was meant to display the id along with "Link".' -- yes exactly that.  Display the ID and have it a link.

Comment: Ah I see, I missed the extra ">" incantation there so that the ID should have appeared between <a href=".."> and </a> -- the first > was what I missed out.

Comment: @delatbabel how we can add hardcoded url in href instead to use built in function by laravel to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, but if you have a variable `$ID` and you want to append it to the end of your URL, you first need to wrap it in php tags, such as:

`<a href="<?=URL("route/{$ID}")?>">LINK</a>`

Or if you are using blade:

`<a href="{{URL("route/{$ID}")}}">LINK</a>`

Hope it helps.